# How do I use TypeScript generics with bind?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to port the open-source library [unbounded](https://github.com/bevry/unbounded) to TypeScript.

It provides a `binder` function that takes a method, binds it to the context along with any arguments, and returns the result with `.unbounded` set to the original method.

In JavaScript it is:

```
function binder (method, context, …args) {
    const unbounded = method.unbounded || method
    const bounded = method.bind(context, ...args)
    Object.defineProperty(bounded, 'unbounded', {
        value: unbounded,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false
    })
    return bounded
}
```

[However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to express this with TypeScript despite numerous attempts.](https://gist.github.com/balupton/c9d3cba3b92b67037ed5bbee40c408b3)

All of my attempts do not meet the following expectations:

```
// arguments should work correctly

function a(this: { local: string }, arg1: string): string {
    return this.local + arg1
}

// should fail:
binder(a, null) // context wrong type
binder(a, {local: 123}) // local wrong type
binder(a, {local: 123}, 'bar') // local wrong type
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})() // arg1 is missing
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 123) // arg1 wrong type
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})(123) // arg1 wrong type
binder(a, {local: 123}, 123) // local and arg1 wrong type
binder(a, {local: 123})(123) // local and arg1 wrong type
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar', 123) // extra arg
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar', 'baz') // extra arg

// should pass:
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 'bar')()
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar')


// return value should work correctly

// should pass
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 'bar')().substr(0)
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar').substr(0)


// extensions should work correctly

interface E extends Function {
    (this: { local: string }, arg1: string): string
    extension?: string
}

const b = function(this: { local: string }, arg1: string): string {
    return this.local + arg1
} as E
b.extension = 'hello'

const bb = binder(b, { local: 'foo' }, 'bar')
// bb.extension should not be present
// bb.unbounded.extension should be present
// bb.unbounded.unbounded should not be present

const bbb = binder(bb, { local: 'foo' }, 'bar')
// bbb.extension should not be present
// bbb.unbounded.extension should be present
// bbb.unbounded.unbounded should not be present
```

I thought that TypeScript 3.2 [CallbableFunction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html) would have helped here, but I cannot figure out how to use it. [It also seems TypeScript has a bug with its implementation that prevents the return types being accurate.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028#issuecomment-444366082)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, basically `binder` has the same behavior as `bind` it just adds the `unbounded` property ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir correct.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, didn’t  `bind()` become unnecessary since we can now preserve context by using arrow functions and/or classes?

Comment: @Kokodoko many use cases which still need `.bind/.call/.apply` — e.g. class methods, event handlers

Comment: Perhaps when you target older JS versions, but otherwise class methods don’t need bind. Event handlers can use arrow functions instead of bind...

Comment: @Kokodoko that is true. I inspected my code. There are two use cases that I use `.bind/apply/call`. First is setting the context of callbacks. Second is to ensure that the bounded function length is accurate: `const a  = (a, b, c) => {}; const b = (...args) => a(…args); const c = a.bind(); console.log(a.length, b.length, c.length) // 3 0 3`. The latter reason, with the former use case, is actually why the `unbounded` package is used: https://github.com/bevry/event-emitter-grouped/blob/master/source/index.js#L53-L57

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir seems there is a bug that may be preventing us from proceeding further this this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028#issuecomment-444366082

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm giving up from my end, I hope you can make more progress. I've updated the original question to make the different code samples clearer, and added a link to all the variations that I've tried.

Comment: @balupton That bug is not about the generics in `bind` but rather for a generic function passed to bind. If `a` were generic for example, then yes, the `bind` method will not work as expected (typescript lacks the ability to model this) But if `a` is not generic we should be able to get things to work.

Answer (score 3):

We can take the overloads of `bind` introduced in [3.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028) and modify them to forward the `unbounded` property you add to the function.

```
type UnboundFunction<T extends Function, TUnbound> = T & {
    unbounded?: TUnbound
}

type BoundFunction<T extends Function, TUnbound> = T & {
    unbounded: TUnbound
}


type BoundFunctionHelper<TResult extends Function, TUnbound, TArgument> = BoundFunction<TResult, undefined extends TUnbound ? TArgument : TUnbound >;

export function binder<T, R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T): BoundFunctionHelper<() => R, TUnbound, typeof method >;
export function binder<T, A extends any[], R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, ...args: A) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: A) => R, TUnbound, typeof method >;
export function binder<T, A0, A extends any[], R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, arg0: A0, ...args: A) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T, arg0: A0): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: A) => R, TUnbound, typeof method >;
export function binder<T, A0, A1, A extends any[], R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, ...args: A) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: A) => R, TUnbound, typeof method>
export function binder<T, A0, A1, A2, A extends any[], R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, ...args: A) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: A) => R, TUnbound, typeof method>;
export function binder<T, A0, A1, A2, A3, A extends any[], R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, ...args: A) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T, arg0: A0, arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: A) => R, TUnbound, typeof method>;
export function binder<T, AX, R, TUnbound = undefined>(method: UnboundFunction<(this: T, ...args: AX[]) => R, TUnbound>, thisArg: T, ...args: AX[]): BoundFunctionHelper<(...args: AX[]) => R, TUnbound, typeof method>;
export function binder(method: UnboundFunction<Function, Function>, context: any, ...args: any[]): BoundFunction<Function, Function> {
    const unbounded = method.unbounded || method
    const bounded = method.bind(context, ...args)
    Object.defineProperty(bounded, 'unbounded', {
        value: unbounded,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false
    })
    return bounded
}


function a(this: { local: string }, arg: string): string {
    return this.local 
}


binder(a, null) // fails as this.local is missing
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})() // fails as arg1 is missing
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 'bar')() // pass
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar') // pass
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 123)() // fail due to incorrect type
binder(a, {local: 123}, 'bar')() // fail due to incorrect type
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar') // fail due to incorrect type
binder(a, {local: 'foo'})('bar', 'bob') // fail due to extra arg
binder(a, {local: 'foo'}, 'bar', 'bob') // unfortunately works, also a problem with the 3.2 implementation of bind. 

// Preserve unbounded type test
function a2(this: { local: string }, arg: string, arg2: string): string {
    return this.local 
}

var unbounded = binder(binder(a2, { local: 'foo'}), undefined, "").unbounded;
var o = { local : "", unbounded };
o.unbounded("", "") // unbounded type reserved trhough mutiple binder calls
```

Comment: Sensational. The only problem I can find with this is `bb.unbounded.extension` and  `bbb.unbounded.extension` are not present.

Comment: @balupton didn't see that part .. the extension part will be harder to get .. we might have to rethink the overloads .. I'll try to get something working tomorrow, I'll post an update if I have one